# how to pass a value to the code behind asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, textbox

Erm i am new to this. How do i pass the value the user enters into a text box to the vb code behind?

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="amount" name="amount" size="15" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ASP.NET-TextBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx).

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"/>
```

Then you can access it from codebehind via it's ID

```
Dim Textbox1Text As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
```

The Text will automatically persisted in [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx) across postbacks by default.

Answer (score 4):

No need to pass the value As its `RunAt = server` you can directly access value of the text box using its `Text` property

Example

```
amount.Value
```

or you can make use of Request collection to get the value of the textbox `Request.Form["amount"]`